# radio button helper with 2 buttons

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I need to display 2 radio buttons horizontally, where the user can only have 1 selected at a time.

`Html.Radiobutton` doesn't seem to group items together.

how can this be achieved?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The radio buttons need to have the same name, but use a different value.

```
<%= Html.RadioButton("myRadioButton", "yes")%>
<%= Html.RadioButton("myRadioButton", "no")%>
<%= Html.RadioButton("myRadioButton", "neither")%>
```

Answer (score 1):

It need same name like this

```
<input  type='radio' name='Rd1' value='true' />

<input  type='radio' name='Rd1'  value='false'/>
```